# Infinite vector-matrix multiplication inside an integral and limit

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, limits

Let $A(t)$ be an infinite matrix where all elements are in $[0,1]$ and let $\vec{p}$ be a stochastic row vector of infinite size. So, $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{1} = 1$ and all elements of $\vec{p}$ are non-negative.

I have the result

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t A(s) \,\mathrm{d}s = A,
\end{equation}

where $A$ is again an infinite matrix.

I wish to determine

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \vec{p} A(s) \,\mathrm{d}s, \tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $\vec{p} A(s)$ is a row vector of infinite size. Is the following correct, and if so, why can I bring the vector $\vec{p}$ outside the limit?

\begin{equation}
(1) \overset{?}{=} \vec{p} \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t A(s) \,\mathrm{d}s = \vec{p} A.
\end{equation}

Element $j$ of $\vec{p} A(s)$ is computed through the infinite series $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty p_i A(s)_{i,j}$, and normally there are conditions that need to be checked to interchange a series, integral and limit.

---

**Edit** To further elaborate on my concerns, since the limit and integral are taken element-wise, the computations for element $j$ of $\vec{p} A(s)$ actually look like

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \sum_{i = 1}^\infty p_i A(s)_{i,j} \,\mathrm{d}s \overset{?}{=} \sum_{i = 1}^\infty p_i \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t A(s)_{i,j} \,\mathrm{d}s = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty p_i A_{i,j}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem, if $\int_0^t \sum_{i = 1}^\infty p_i |A(s)_{i,j}|\,ds<\infty$, then the series commutes with the integral. Then you can pass the limit inside the series at least if the latter converges uniformly.